# group by comma separated list of Ids in TSQL not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on creating a stored procedure. I have data in this format

**InteractiionId(pk) EmployeeId(fk) Reasons**

```
1                   107           66
2                   107           68
3                   107           66,69
4                   98           71
5                   98           71
6                   98           69,71,68 
7                   90           68 
8                   90           69,68 
9                   90           66,71,68
```

I need to find for each employee count of reasons like this

**EmployeeID  ReasonsCount**

```
  107    66(2)
    107     68(1)
    107     69(1) 
    98     71(3)
    98     68(1)
    98     69(1)
    90     68(3)
    90     69(1)
    90     66(1)
    90     71(1)
```

I am trying to do it like this:

```
select IdEmployee, E.FirstName,E.LastName,  count(reasons), Reasons FROM Interaction I
 LEFT JOIN Employee E
 ON I.IdEmployee = E.Id


-- where
 --    IdEmployee = 95 OR 
--    IdEmployee = 98 OR
  --  IdEmployee = 107
group by  IdEmployee, E.FirstName,E.LastName, Reasons
```

but it is not working. Please suggest solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: @jarlh This is completely wrong. I can tell you 5 real examples on prima vista and many more, where CSV in the database is working better than if the data is normalized. And if you are right and it is bad practice, why in `SQL Sever  2016` Microsoft  added `STRING_SPLIT` and `STRING_AGG`? What you have just said is an old rule, which does not reflect the real life.

Comment: @Asif Hameed Does my code helps you

Comment: @gotqn, well, after having a look at the answers below I still think it's a bad idea!

Comment: @jarlh I am not saying that it is a good practice. I am saying that in the SQL there aren't many `golden rules` (rules which are always true), and basically it depends on the situation. Saying that something `never` should be done is bad idea for me ;)

Comment: @gotqn, I'd say there actually are some important rules - that all less experienced users should follow. (And later, with experience, you can chose to break those rules.)

Comment: @gotqn: why in SQL Sever 2016 Microsoft added STRING_SPLIT and STRING_AGG?

Because it is impossible to resist the tide flowing against you. SQL Server supports lots of functionality that is not advisable. And MS does try to provide functionality requested by users - at least to some degree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;with cte
as
(
select * from #temp t
cross apply
SplitStrings_Numbers(c,',') b
)
select b,cast(item as varchar(10))+' ('+ cast(count(item) as varchar(10))+')' as cnt
from
cte
group by b,item
```

I have used [split strings function](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) to split the values

Answer (score 0):

You could use inline split string  like this

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE
(
   InteractiionId int,
   EmployeeId int ,
   Reasons varchar(200)
)

INSERT INTO @SampleData
VALUES
  (1, 107, '66'),
  (2, 107, '68'),
  (3, 107, '66,69'),
  (4, 98 , '71'),
  (5, 98 , '71'),
  (6, 98 , '69,71,68'), 
  (7, 90 , '68'), 
  (8, 90 , '69,68'), 
  (9, 90 , '66,71,68')

;WITH temp AS 
(
   SELECT  *,
         CAST('<X>' + replace(sd.Reasons, ',','</X><X>') +'</X>'  AS XML ) AS XmlValue
   FROM @SampleData sd
)
SELECT  t.EmployeeId, CONCAT(c.[Value], '(', count(*), ')') 
FROM temp t
CROSS APPLY
(
   SELECT t.x.value('.', 'varchar(100)') AS Value
   FROM t.XmlValue.nodes('X') AS t(x)
) c
GROUP BY t.EmployeeId, c.[Value]
ORDER BY t.EmployeeId desc
```

Demo link: http://rextester.com/EHL21890

Answer (score 0):

```
;With cte(InteractiionId, EmployeeId, Reasons)
 AS
(
SELECT 1, 107,  '66'        UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 107,  '68'        UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 107,  '66,69'     UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 98 , '71'         UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 98 , '71'         UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 98 , '69,71,68'   UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 90 , '68'         UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 90 , '69,68'      UNION ALL
SELECT 9, 90 , '66,71,68' 
)

,CteCount AS (
    SELECT a.InteractiionId
        ,a.EmployeeId
        ,Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Reasons
    FROM (
        SELECT InteractiionId
            ,EmployeeId
            ,CAST('<M>' + REPLACE(Reasons, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Reasons
        FROM cte
        ) AS A
    CROSS APPLY Reasons.nodes('/M') AS Split(a)
    )

    SELECT EmployeeId
    ,CONCAT(Reasons,'(' ,ReasonCounts,')') AS ReasonsCount
     FROM (
    SELECT EmployeeId,Reasons,ReasonCounts FROM 
       (
        SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeId,Reasons
            ,COUNT(Reasons) OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeId,Reasons ORDER BY EmployeeId
                ) AS ReasonCounts
        FROM CteCount
        ) Dt
    ) Final
ORDER BY Final.EmployeeId DESC
```

OutPut

```
EmployeeId    ReasonsCount
------------------------
107             66(2)
107             68(1)
107             69(1)
98              68(1)
98              69(1)
98              71(3)
90              66(1)
90              68(3)
90              69(1)
90              71(1)
```